# executing python unittest with ipdb

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, ipdb

Typically I run my python unit test with:

```
python -m unittest test.<module-name>
```

I would like to debug my tests using `ipdb` but I cannot figure out how to invoke the`unittest` module in manner similar to the command above.

The directory structure is:

- `base/src` for the source code
- `base/test` for the test code

Tests run from the `base` directory.

The preference is to 'run' & 'debug' test cases in the same manner, specifically the preference is to debug with `ipdb` in a similar manner to the python command above.

#### FYI

Interpreter is `python2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with the unittest module from the standardlib, but the testrunner [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html) has at least pdb (not ipdb) support. Just invoke it with

```
pytest --pdb
```

and it drops into pdb with the first failure.